# Excel vlookup functions

Tags: excel, count, sum, vlookup, sumifs

[image]

Team, here i want a formula which acts like vlookup by comparing MDL (table 1) and row label(table-2), if it matches then it has to take the corresponding NO value(table 1) and then search in table-2 and once find it
it has to sum all the values and then enter them in value column(table 1)

Comment: What's the expected result for `P104-QKIT`? There is one value in table-2 for that row, so the result should be 1, or there is no value in table-2 for row label `P104-QK1T` and `NO` column 4, so the result should be 0?

Comment: if i use normal vlookup then the results shows as "1" , but i want it to calculate all the numbers before that and shows as "2" as i shown in green colour

Comment: Perhaps you should try sumproduct().

Comment: What's the function of NO column in table 1? Would it have to sum up all values in the row of table 2 matching the model, or all values from the row regardless the value of NO column in table 1?

Comment: here in table -1 both MDL & NO are look up value

Comment: in value column in table-1 , i want sum value as the result by comparing with table - 2

Comment: So you want to sum all the numbers up to `NO`? So `NO` is a value you provide? It isn't something that we look up, right? What version of Excel do you have? Do you have access to `FILTER`? Also, please add all of these clarifications to your original question, as many users will not bother reading through both the question and comments.

Comment: It's not clear why you need to match the NO values given at the end of the day you're adding them all up - SUMIFS should do what you're looking for.